# Custom position of in-panel widget ArcGIS Web App builder

Tags: style, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget, css, arcgis-custom-widget

I need the opportunity to toggle between 'draggable' position of an in-panel widget (ArcGIS Web App Builder 2.19) and its fixed position in the footer of an application. Is there an option to do it for now?

I tried to solve it via forcibly changing a widget position by `.setPosition()` method and adding some css-styles (with a lot of `!important` rules) to a `.jimu-panel` class but it doesn't work correctly. What am I missing?